# Почему RecyclerView равен null?

Tags: java, android

Код Фрагмента:

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment {
    private String id;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_all);

        ActivityFragments activityFragments = (ActivityFragments) getActivity();
        id = activityFragments.getMyData();


       // AllResultPresenter allResultPresenter = new AllResultPresenter(id,ResultsFragment.this);



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); // there is Error; null

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        AllResultPresenter allResultPresenter = new AllResultPresenter(id,ResultsFragment.this);

    }

    public void showAllResult(ArrayList<Result> allResultResponses) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AllResultsAdapter(this, allResultResponses));
    }
}
```

Код Активности:

```
public class ActivityFragments extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private String mId;
    Fragment fragment;
    Class fragmentClass;
   FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fragment = null;
        fragmentClass = null;
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentClass = HelloFragment.class;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();


        //
      //  Intent kek = getIntent();
      //  String kek1 = kek.getStringExtra("ExamFragment");
      //  if(kek1 != null) {
//            Log.d("Please", kek1);
      //  }

/*
        if(kek1 == null){
        }else {
            fragmentClass = ExamFragment.class;
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();

        }

*/

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mId = intent.getStringExtra("id"); //work
        Log.d("qwerty",mId);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, mId, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        String testMeNeed = intent.getStringExtra("ExamFragment");
        if(testMeNeed.equals("ExamFragment")){
        Log.d("MyFirstFragment", testMeNeed);
        fragmentClass = ExamFragment.class;
                try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        }

        }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.exam, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        /*
        fragment = null;
        fragmentClass = null;
        if(fragmentClass == null) {
            fragmentClass = HelloFragment.class;
        }
        */

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentClass = ExamFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentClass = ResultsFragment.class;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentClass = RemindersFragment.class;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        }
       // if(fragment == null) {
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       // }

        // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
      //   fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
        // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
        item.setChecked(true);
        // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
        setTitle(item.getTitle());


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


        return true;
    }


    public String getMyData() {
        return mId;
    }
```

Код разметки Фрагмента:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asus.hackaton.view.examview.ResultsFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="myFragment with Results"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Код разметки RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_all"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: а на какую строку ругается что null ?

Comment: У вас что-то с форматированием кода. Не ясно даже есть ли у вас в разметке фрагмента собственно RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

Судя по косвенным признакам, в первый фрагмент кода с разметкой, он же третий фрагмент во всем вопросе, это R.layout.fragment_results. Он не содержит элемента `RecyclerView` с id `recycler_view_all`. Поэтому `findViewById()` возвращает закономерный null.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_all);
```

Ваш `RecyclerView` в другой разметке, но как она называется и где она используется в коде, из вопроса понять невозможно.